# Cannot run docker image argon2 invalid ELF header

Tags: node.js, docker

My dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "./bin/www"]
```

First I run docker run -p 3000:3000 -d --name node-app node-app-image
It gives me a hash
Then I run docker ps to check running container which is empty
Then I run docker ps -a It gives me this:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
4b5a2deea8bd   node-app-image   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago   Exited (1) 4 minutes ago             node-app
```

there was exception in log: return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename)); Error: /app/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi-v3/argon2.node: invalid ELF header at Object. (/app/node_modules/argon2/argon2.js:9:56) code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'

Comment: Well, what do the logs say `docker container logs --details -t 4b5a2deea8bd`? What does your program _actually do_?

Comment: Your container has exited already so, please post your log details to find out exact issue why container exit

Comment: wow there was exception in log:

return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
 Error: /app/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi-v3/argon2.node: invalid ELF header
 at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/argon2/argon2.js:9:56)
code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'

Comment: My code run perfectly without docker
does it mean the library does not work with docker?

Comment: Do you have a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) that excludes the `node_modules` directory?  If you `COPY` the host's `node_modules` tree into a container you could get this error.

Comment: thanks I fixed with .dockerignore file that excludes the node_modules