# Anyone know what I need to do to get this app working on heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm horribly new. So, I'm sure it's something very obvious.
This is a simple blog posting app.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZzoq.png)

Here's the logs:

```
    2022-08-06T05:01:07.613012+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2022-08-06T05:01:09.866047+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
    2022-08-06T05:01:11.802781+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2022-08-06T05:01:11.802803+00:00 app[web.1]: > webdev-blogpub@1.0.0 start
    2022-08-06T05:01:11.802803+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
    2022-08-06T05:01:11.802803+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261482+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1189
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261495+00:00 app[web.1]: return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261496+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261496+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261497+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261498+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1189:18)
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261498+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261499+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261499+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261499+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261500+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261500+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261500+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261500+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261501+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261501+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.261501+00:00 app[web.1]: }
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.447473+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2022-08-06T05:01:12.514128+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2022-08-06T05:01:34.971754+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=webdev-blogpub.herokuapp.com request_id=1a97248d-cbfb-49c2-9a66-7387a694050d fwd="184.91.86.250" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2022-08-06T05:01:35.240071+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=webdev-blogpub.herokuapp.com request_id=7347a626-2ad0-4544-a735-b097c232c83d fwd="184.91.86.250" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2022-08-06T05:03:26.310277+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=webdev-blogpub.herokuapp.com request_id=8f258b45-8c3f-409c-b783-74b6e922de58 fwd="184.91.86.250" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2022-08-06T05:03:26.806445+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=webdev-blogpub.herokuapp.com request_id=396e2ae6-f5b6-46bc-8950-6c4f30c24a39 fwd="184.91.86.250" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2022-08-06T05:06:02.706235+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=webdev-blogpub.herokuapp.com request_id=1743caa9-b5a1-41e0-8906-7060278358ef fwd="184.91.86.250" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2022-08-06T05:06:02.914897+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=webdev-blogpub.herokuapp.com request_id=9e55e940-3fe6-4434-ac79-f9f09f9de4c2 fwd="184.91.86.250" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70408913/cannot-run-docker-image-argon2-invalid-elf-header  (It doesn't have an answer, but it does have comments which might point to an answer for you)

Comment: please post the code as a text not an image.